# Extended generic type

Tags: java, generics, extends

I've got the following code:

```
public class GenericsTest<T extends Number> {

    public void doSomething(T v1, T v2) {
    }

    public void test()
    {
        GenericsTest<T> test = new GenericsTest<>();
        //test.doSomething(new Integer(0), new Integer(1)); Not ok
    }
}
```

In `test()` I create `GenericsTest<T>` where `T` extends `Number`, but I can not pass any number.

> The method doSomething(T, T) in the type GenericsTest is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Integer, Integer)

Why I can not pass an `Integer` if `T` is `Number` as well as `Integer`?

Comment: Your test method should not be in the same class. How do you invoke test()?

Comment: That's because the variable `test` is a `GenericsTest<T>` instead of a `GenericsTest<Integer>`.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht that does not really matter I guess. He can perfectly write his code like this, since it is not really intended to do anything except show him how it works.

Comment: @Timo: Yes it does, because this is why the T is coming from inside the object and thus can be anything. Would the test method be outside (like in one of the answers), you wouldn't have a chance to write such code.

Comment: The perfect anti-example would have been: new GenericsTest<Double>().test(), where it is immediately obvious that Integer would be invalid to be used.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht, oh, ok. Now it's clear to me. You could post your answer.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht you're right :) I missed that the compiler would accept the example because a `T` is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like suggested, I will try to make things more clear with an anti-example:

As the `test()` method is inside the generic class, the `T` parameter used inside the method is the parameter of the class. This means, a `new GenericTest<Double>().test()` would create a `GenericTest<Double>` inside, while a `new GenericTest<Integer>().test()` would create a nice `GenericTest<Integer>` inside. As at compile-time it is unclear which concrete type for the `T` parameter will be used, the compiler raises the error when concrete types like `Integer` are used with the `GenericTest<T>` object created inside the `test()` method.

It would be perfectly fine to call `new GenericTest<Integer>()` within the `test()` method, but still a little bit confusing. This is why I would recommend to put such test methods outside the class, where such things become immediately clear.

(The answer moving the test code to a `main()` method does exactly that.)

Answer (score 3):

you need to define the generic instance with a valid type

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final GenericsTest<Integer> test = new GenericsTest<>();
    test.doSomething(new Integer(0), new Integer(1)); // now is ok
}
```

then you need to add constraint to the method doSomething

```
 public <T extends Number> void doSomething(T v1, T v2) {

    }

    public void testMethod() {
        final GenericsTest<T> test = new GenericsTest<>();
        test.doSomething(new Integer(0), new Integer(1));
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately  this is not the answer I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

It's not applicable because `T` is some subtype of `Number`. I.e. it can be `Double` too. But, you can specify the `T` at constructor invocation:

```
    public void test()
    {
        GenericsTest<Integer> test = new GenericsTest<>();
        test.doSomething(new Integer(0), new Integer(1)); //Okay now
    }
```